# Resizing Dynamic Matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I'm having troubles with something really silly. But I'm not been able to solve the problem. I designed a function that build a column matrix from a string resizing dynamically.

```
typedef struct{
double  ** m_;
size_t rows_, cols_;
}matrix_t;

int loadCol(char* str, matrix_t* col){
    size_t size=0; char* ptr;
    if(str==NULL)   return 0;
    if((col=(matrix_t*)malloc(sizeof(matrix_t)))==NULL) return 0;
    if((col->m_=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)))==NULL) return 0;
    ptr = strtok(str, "|");
    do{
        if(((col->m_)[0]=(double*)realloc((col->m_), sizeof(double)*(size+1)))==NULL){
            eraseMatrix(col); 
            return 0;
        }
        (col->m_)[0][size]=atof(ptr); /*SIGSEV*/
        size++;
    }while((ptr=strtok(NULL,"|"))!=NULL);
    col->cols_ = 1; col->rows_ = size;
    return size;
}
```

I debug with gdb and the problem seems to be in the assignment line mark with the comment SIGSEV. Also when the program's flow goes out from this function scope col->cols_ have incorrect data.
Where is the problem in my function?

Comment: So I should define double*** m in the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For col to be modified in a function and the modifications reflected to the caller, a pointer to col needs to be passed as `matrix_t **col`. Then col has to be dereferenced in the function.
The caller would use `loadCol ( str, &col);` if col is declared as `matrix_t *col = NULL;`

```
int loadCol(char* str, matrix_t** col){
    size_t size=0; char* ptr;
    if(str==NULL)   return 0;
    if((*col=(matrix_t*)malloc(sizeof(matrix_t)))==NULL) return 0;
    if(((*col)->m_=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)))==NULL) return 0;
    ptr = strtok(str, "|");
    do{
        if((((*col)->m_)[0]=(double*)realloc(((*col)->m_)[0], sizeof(double)*(size+1)))==NULL){
            //eraseMatrix(col);
            return 0;
        }
        ((*col)->m_)[0][size]=atof(ptr);
        size++;
    }while((ptr=strtok(NULL,"|"))!=NULL);
    (*col)->cols_ = 1; (*col)->rows_ = size;
    return size;
}
```

strpbrk and strtod may also be used to parse values from the string.

```
int loadCol(char* str, matrix_t** col){
    size_t size=0; char* ptr;
    char *next = NULL;
    if(str==NULL)   return 0;
    if((*col=(matrix_t*)malloc(sizeof(matrix_t)))==NULL) return 0;
    if(((*col)->m_=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)))==NULL) return 0;
    next = str;
    while((ptr=strpbrk(next,"0123456789-+."))!=NULL) {
        if((((*col)->m_)[0]=(double*)realloc(((*col)->m_)[0], sizeof(double)*(size+1)))==NULL){
            //eraseMatrix(col);
            return 0;
        }
        ((*col)->m_)[0][size]=strtod(ptr,&next);
        size++;
    }
    (*col)->cols_ = 1; (*col)->rows_ = size;
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to solve most of the problem. But there is still one little bug. The first value of ptr isn't property loaded. For example, if str="1.0|1.0|1.3|0.3" col will have 0.0, 1.0, 1.3 and 0.3 in m_. what going on? why isn't the program evaluating properly the first value of str?